# How to run jenkins build alternatively on agent nodes?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Let's say I have a job A and also a agent configured. I want to run build 1 of Job A on master and build 2 of Job A on agent node.
Is there an option to achieve that ?

OR

Is there a way where my job looks at controller and if it already finds a build running, then start the next build on agent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you intending to run in parallel or just alternate? (Not a good idea to [run jobs on master;](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=34930989#content/view/34930989) could configure a node to run on same host as "master".). Seems to be parallel and you have restricted to one executor each on master and agent (you can have more, in which case any advice may be moot).

Nevertheless, Jenkins queue job allocation to executors is "sticky"; it tries to run where last run, unless unavailable. This can lead to overloading in nodes. So the M,A,M,A pattern is unnatural.

There are plugins that might help: [Least Load](https://plugins.jenkins.io/leastload/), [Scoring Load Balancer](https://plugins.jenkins.io/scoring-load-balancer/), but maybe not.

Perhaps an approach would be to restrict your job using a label and have a post-build groovy step that moves the label to the other upon success for the next run or two labels and the job self-modifies the label to match the other.

Comment: I want to run the builds concurrently. The issue is, I have 2 slave nodes with same label. But, every build of the job is running only on slave-1. I have never seen it triggering a build on slave-2. If i run 3 concurrent builds, all of them are stacked up on slave-1. How do suggest, I can fix it ?

Comment: Do you have only one executor per node? Did you enable on the job: [   ] Execute concurrent builds if necessary? If you don't tick parallel, they wait.

Comment: I have 4 executors on each node. I dont see 'Execute concurrent builds if necessary' on my job config but i see 'Do not allow concurrent builds' which is unchecked. That means I am allowing concurrent builds.

Comment: Scoring Load Balancer met the requirement. Thanks @Ian