# Run Job on either node from a pool of dynamic nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have many different jobs. Each job requires exclusive access to a physical device during its execution. There are five such identical devices, i.e. each job can use any of the five devices for its execution.

I'd like to be able to trigger 20 jobs and then want Jenkins to provision five agents and execute 5 jobs in parallel until the queue is emptied.

I've setup 5 dynamic agent templates. Each template having a different IP of a physical device as an environment variable and each template being limited to an *Instance Capacity* of 1. That should take care of the exclusive access.

First I have given each template the same label: 'my5devices' and set the jobs to use this label:

`agent {label 'my5devices'}`

yet Jenkins only ever provisioned one agent. In the queued jobs I could see, they were all waiting for this single dynamic agent to have a free executor.

I was observing the same, when given each template a different label and changing the job:

`agent { label 'device1 || device2 || device3 || device4 || device5' }`

It seems Jenkins never provisions more than one agent and therefore only ever runs one job after the other.

Comment: See this [S/O response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64132274/598141). You can delete the workspace of one job and trigger another, then it to confirm stickiness. Install [Least Load](https://plugins.jenkins.io/leastload/) and should be OK.

Comment: Thank you, @ian-w . Seems both mentioned plugins do influence scheduling onto nodes that are already available. It doesn't trigger the creation of new dynamic nodes.

Comment: Misunderstood the issue. What kind of agents aee you (re-)creating? Can you not just have 5 permanent agents and use [lockable reources](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/), in conjunction w/least load?

Comment: Thank you, @ian-w. Didn't know about about 'lockable resources'. That is of help. I'm currently using dynamic agents (docker-cloud). I could create permanent agents, but I guess, I would lose some 'dynamic' features (such as: updates to the image of a dynamic agent,  only using and paying for resources when they are needed, no need to ensure the agents are restarted if they somehow crash and having all config only in jenkins vs. having to sync credentials with an agent)).

Comment: Currently I've implemented a 'stub' job which will start both agents when needed and keep them there for a minute, to allow jenkins to see them and schedule jobs accordingly. It is however an ugly hack.